# Disable file manipulation in R?

Tags: r, windows, cmd

I want to execute an R script on a remote server.  I have a script that runs, and will run on the server... but as a safety feature I want to disable file manipulations (think file.create(), file.remove(), etc.)

Is this possible?  Is there a line I can put at the top of the script, or even better that I can add to the command line call, that would allow the file to be able to read from a local csv file, but can't write/modify/delete any?

Comment: Usually you'd handle this with permissions on the OS side. I don't think there is a feasible way of implementing such restrictions in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider locking the server folders for read-only access as opposed to script level directive. And in Windows, this can be done under **Security** tab under folder's **Properties** (right-click menu) where you can even designate access privileges (Allow/Deny) by different user groups:

[image: Security Windows Folders]

With only *Write* denied for user, any [file manipulation method](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/files.html) will raise a *Warning* or *FALSE* value but not an *Error*:

```
file.create("C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\NewFile.txt")
# [1] FALSE
# Warning message:
# In file.create("C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\NewFile.txt") :
#  cannot create file 'C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\NewFile.txt', reason 'Permission denied'

file.rename("C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\CurrentFile.txt",
            "C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\CurrentFile.txt")
# [1] FALSE

file.copy("C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\CurrentFile.txt",
          "C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\NewFile.txt")
# [1] FALSE
# Warning message:
# In file.create("C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\NewFile.txt") :
#  cannot create file 'C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\NewFile.txt', reason 'Permission denied'
```

And user can still read files without any error:

```
con <- file(description="C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\CurrentFile.txt", open="r")
close(con)

df <- read.table("C:\\Path\\To\\Read-Only\\Folder\\CurrentFile.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks.  This helps.  Problem is, I'm using a server dedicated to automation.  is there a way to invoke this sort of thing on command line during the R script call?  Files will still need to be able to be written for other jobs, I just wanted to restrict it whenever this action is called.

Comment: Or is this something that can be done once on the OS side specifically for R?

Comment: Consider wrapping the action conditionally with `if` logic in code. The user running script might not have admin rights to restrict read/write privileges. Nor do you really want to leave an application to handle filesystem access and security.